# iPhone 7 Plus have two WiFi MAC address

Tags: iphone, network

I know some devices have two WiFi MACs (one for 2.4GHz and one for 5GHz).

In some network monitoring like Fing.app my iPhone is displayed twice with the same IP but totally different MAC.

PS: but "both" devices have a different bonjour name.

Any more info on this?

Comment: PS I can remember at once stage that IOS was supposed to generate a virtual MAC adress for safety I'm.wondering is this the case here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since iOS 8 the system generates a randomized MAC address. I thought it was every time you connect to a different network and on every restart.

So you have technically 2 separate networks which means you have also 2 different MAC addresses.